# Подсчитать количество единиц в двоичной записи огромного числа

Tags: c#, консоль, числа, системы-счисления

Задача: Сколько единиц содержится в двоичной записи значения выражения: 4^2020 + 2^2017 – 15?

Так как число превышает допустимое значение типа double, моя программа выводит неправильный ответ: vr = infinity, count = 1. (count должен равняться 2015)

```
    double vr = Math.Pow(4, 2020) + Math.Pow(2, 2017) - 15; // наше выражение
    string b = Convert.ToString((int)vr, 2);
    int count = 0; //счётчик единиц
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] == '1')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь BigInteger.Pow, а не Math.Pow

Comment: Считать большие числа не надо, это задача на логику, решается в уме

Comment: @Kalmankantaja, спасибо, ответ получился правильный!

Comment: добавь ожидаемый результат в вопрос

Comment: @MBo всё равно полезно знать как работать с большими числами.

Comment: Остаётся понять, является ли эта задача хорошей учебной задачей по программированию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MBo! В двоичной записи числа 4 одна единица (100), и в какую целую степень его не возводи, так одна единица и останется. Например: 4^2=16 (10000). Тоже самое касается и двойки. Сразу преобразуем 4^2020 в 2^4040.

Далее, в двоичной системе. Если к одному числу вида 1 с нулями добавить меньшее такого же вида, то получится 2 единицы, например: 10000+100=10100. Теперь найдём разность большого числа и 15, например: 1000 0000 0000-1111=111 1111 0001, то есть такое вычитание добавляет Z-4 единиц, где Z - степень наименьшей единицы в числе, которая равна степени меньшего числа. Итого ответ равен 2+Z-4=Z-2

Вот и ответ: 2015.

И вправду ошибка была, даже две.

Comment: Где-то просчитались, т. к. правильный ответ - 2015.

Comment: Там не разность,  а сумма двух больших степеней, бОльшая просто добавит одну единицу

Comment: @MBo так и есть. Как говорится, смотришь в книгу - видишь (фи)совсем другое.

Comment: _В десятичной записи числа 4_ - в десятичной записи в числе 4 - нет единиц

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием класса BigInteger:

```
    BigInteger vr = BigInteger.Pow(4, 2020) + BigInteger.Pow(2, 2017) -15;
    Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.PopCount(vr));
```

Comment: [BigInteger.PopCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.popcount?view=net-8.0).